# Cloning System.Windows.Media.Matrix

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Since **System.Windows.Media.Matrix** doesn't provide Clone() method, what is the best possible approach to clone a matrix.

I am right now using the following approaches:

1. Create a new matrix from the original matrix.

   public Matrix Clone(Matrix source)
   {
     Matrix dest = new Matrix(source.M11,source.M12, source.M21, source.M22, source.OffsetX, source.OffsetY);
     return dest;
   }
2. Multiply source matrix with identity matrix.

   public Matrix Clone(Matrix source)
   {
     return Matrix.Multiply(source, Matrix.Identity);
   }

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Creating a new Matrix from another one is as simple as this:

```
var newMatrix = oldMatrix;
```

This is because Matrix is a [`struct`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0taef578.aspx), not a `class`, and hence a value type, not a reference type.

For more information see [Value Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1ax56ch.aspx).